# Grub listings from two separate drives

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, grub

I have an NVME drive with Windows 10 and Linux Mint installed on it.  The grub recognizes both.  I just moved an old HDD with Manjaro and Kali installed into my pc.  The grub from the NVME does not recognize anything on the HDD, but the grub on the HDD is able to recognize the two OS's from the NVME drive.

Edit:

- Have been using an NVME with dual-boot Windows 10 and Mint for several months.
- Installed old HDD with dual-boot Manjaro and Kali.
- Grub from NVME does not recognize either of the systems on the HDD.
- Grub from HDD immediately recognized all four systems.
- Ran commands for sudo grub-install and sudo update-grub from within mint.
- Grub from NVME now recognizes Kali, but not Manjaro.

I just realized that the Grub on the HDD stopped displaying Kali as an option, but shows the two systems on the other drive.  Is there a limit to the number of partitions that grub is able to 'see' or display in the boot menu?

I have never had to play around with grub before, so I am a little confused on how the HDD grub saw the other OS's before booting and updating, and how the NVME grub still can't see manjaro even after updating.

How to I get the NVME grub to let me boot into the operation systems that are installed on the HDD?

Comment: Have you run `grub-update` or its alternative for your OS's to tell the NVMe installation which disks it should look at?

Comment: yes I have run grub-update and it did nothing.  os-probe doesn't recognize anything on the HDD either.

Comment: Are the operating systems booting in the native UEFI mode or in the legacy BIOS mode? GRUB can only boot operating systems that can be booted in the same mode GRUB itself is booting in. Is the Manjaro installation encrypted or is there something else that might make it difficult to detect?

Comment: Everything is booting in UEFI mode.  I just checked the manjaro grub and it recognizes all four OS's, while the grub that was installed with mint is seeing everything except for manjaro.